# Vimrc: When backupdir is set, every save prompts "press enter to continue"

Tags: vim

When I add the following line to my .vimrc:

```
set backupdir=~/.vim/backup
```

I get the following prompt every time I save a file with ':w':

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

which is getting to be a pain fast. (Edit) Furthermore, there's nothing actually being displayed besides this prompt (i.e. no new information).

Notes:

- The prompt seems to be independent of whether I have 'set directory' or 'set backup' in vimrc.
- I do not get the error if I am editing a file that is in my home directory, such as ~/.vimrc itself.
- Yes, the folder exists and backup files are being stored there successfully:

  $ ls ~/.vim/backup

  test~   test.txt~
- (Edit) Changing cmdheight to a value of 3 or greater makes the command prompt go away. However, it doesn't fix the underlying problem -- there is no additional text being displayed here (just ""test.txt" 10L, 255C written"), so I don't know what error is being thrown if any.
- (Edit) I get this prompt even if I comment out everything in my .vimrc file except set backupdir=~/.vim/backup. I don't have any plugins.

Can I stop this message prompt from appearing, yet keep my backup directory? Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2):

From [VIM Documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/message.html#hit-enter),

> **Press ENTER or type command to continue**
>
> This message is given when there is something on the screen for you to
>   read, and the screen is about to be redrawn:
>   - After executing an external command (e.g., ":!ls" and "=").
>   - Something is displayed on the status line that is longer than the width of   the window, or runs into the 'showcmd' or 'ruler' output.

So vim is trying to tell you something, some error message or something and your cmd window height is not sufficient and hence its prompting you with a message

To overcome this, documentation suggests,

> To reduce the number of hit-enter prompts:
>
> - Set 'cmdheight' to 2 or higher.
> - Add flags to 'shortmess'.
> - Reset 'showcmd' and/or 'ruler'.

I suggest you check out what error vim is outputting before trying to eliminate the prompt.

You might also want to read [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoiding_the_%22Hit_ENTER_to_continue%22_prompts)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I should have mentioned this earlier. I can get the prompt to disappear with a cmdheight of 3 or more. However, there is no message being displayed (in either case). So it seems there is some other problem. Also, what error could I be running into when saving, and why doesn't vim tell me? Thanks again for responding!

Comment: check your .vimrc if you are running some commands, with `silent` optipon

Comment: I retried it will all other options commented out except for backupdir, and same result. (Even commented out nocompatible, so a blank vimrc except the line 'set backupdir=~/.vim/backup'. Weird. Maybe a permissions thing?

Comment: Yea, it *may* be a permission issue. I made my backup dir read only and this prompt comes up but only difference if I am getting an error message along with it **"E510  Can't make backup file (add ! to override)"** I strongly suspect that your backup files are being updated every time you say :w. Also are you using some custom color_scheme which might be messing with the visibility of the error message?

Comment: Just check what it says when you say `:hi Error` And correlate this with your background color and see if this is the culprit

Comment: Thanks again for all the advice! I tried set:background=dark. Then I saved with :w, hit Enter at the prompt, and typed :hi Error. I repeated with set:background=light. In both background schemes, here is the output:

"Error          xxx term=reverse cterm=bold ctermfg=7 ctermbg=1 guifg=White guibg=Red"

I don't understand it...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9629/discussion-between-bo1024-and-pavan-manjunath)

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet figured out the answer to this.

An odd data point is that this conflict appears to only be true when my backup directory is in my home folder (or ~/.vim/backup, or ?). Setting it to a different folder appears to resolve the mystery error.

Comment: What happens if you use the absolute path to your home dir instead of `~`?

Comment: I also recommend using absolute path, like `/cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/youruser/tmp`, it fixed this error for me.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  if !isdirectory(expand("~/.vim/backupdir/"))
    silent !echo "Creating backup dir..."
    silent !mkdir -p ~/.vim/backupdir
  endif
  if !isdirectory(expand("~/.vim/swap/"))
    silent !echo "Creating swap dir..."
    silent !mkdir -p ~/.vim/swap
  endif
  if !isdirectory(expand("~/.vim/undo/"))
    silent !echo "Creating undo dir..."
    silent !mkdir -p ~/.vim/undo
  endif

  set backupdir^=~/.vim/backup//              " where to put backup files
  set directory^=~/.vim/swap//                " where to put swap files
  set undodir^=~/.vim/undo//                  " where to put undo files
```